# How HTML in BUILD DIR is linked to JS in SRC DIR when we create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

When we run command  `create-react-app`  to configure our initial react app. Then it creates the app directory with the given name with sub-directories in it. When we run the app by using `npm start` then it deploys the **index.html** file in the **public**  directory within APP directory . My question is how **index.js** file in **src** directory is linked to **index.html** file while there is no `<script>` tag linking it ?

Answer (score 0):

The magic (logic) lies in the package “react-scripts”. It’s a library of scripts which does the bundling of your source code and manipulate the HTML with bundled script.

By the way, if you want to study the code of the script, just run `npm eject` and you’ll get `scripts` folder in root which will contain `start` and `build` script.